# How to install public package inside private package npm

Tags: javascript, typescript, github, npm

I have private package in github npm registry. In my private package I installed public package.

When I want to install my private package in my project, I get following error:

```
404 Not Found - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/axios
'axios@^0.21.1' is not in the npm registry.
```

How can I solve this problem?